# If not enough current then switch

Tags: batteries, raspberry-pi, solar-energy

(Sorry, I am a newbie but here I go..)

I have a 5W 12V solar panel stepping down to 5V. The current then goes through a charger that already regulates to the required voltage for the battery. This then goes out to a step up from 3.7V-4.2V to 5V. Then this goes to a raspberry pi zero. I would like it so that whenever the solar panel doesn't produce more than 100mA to the charger then the current will be stopped.

Comment: Which current? The one from panel or the one to te Raspberry? You shouldn't worry much about the current from PV panel.

Comment: Why would you step down to 5, down to 4 then back up to 5? Furthermore, is your 100mA check for brownout? If so, it would probably be easier to measure an undervoltage condition than an undercurrent condition.